# Convergent series to a power between 0 and 1

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have proved if a$_n$ is convergent then the series of a$_n^p$ is convergent for p>1 but am now trying to prove if this series is convergent or not for p between 0 and 1 and don't know where to start.

Comment: You are given that the **sequence** $a_n$ converges and want to investigate whether the **series** $\sum a_n^p$ converges?

Comment: If you take $p$ very small the term $a_n^p$ gets  very large, so it shouldn't be true.

Comment: sorry - I am given $Sigma$ a$_n$ converges so want to prove if $Sigma$a$_n^p$ converges or not for p between 0 and 1

Answer (score 1):

You can't conclude.

$$\sum\frac1{n^2}$$ and $$\sum\frac1{n^3}$$ converge, but

$$\sum\frac1{(n^2)^{1/2}}$$ diverges and $$\sum\frac1{(n^3)^{1/2}}$$ converges.